# Program with named pipes sometimes working sometimes fails

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes

Hello I am trying to do a program in c that uses named pipes to communicate with another program but if i run it more than once it fails most of the time with occasionally working perfectly, even though i don't change anything between tests.
Here is the code for  arbitro.c the program that i execute first

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <signal.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd,id1,cont_pront=0,i=0; 
    char nomejog[40]="",instrucao[40]="";
    // FIFO file path 
        char * myfifo = "myfifo";
    // Creating the named file(FIFO) 
        mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
do{
    fd = open(myfifo,O_RDONLY); 
        if(fd == -1){
            fprintf(stdout, "Erro a abrir.\n");
        }
        // First open in read only and read 
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        read(fd, nomejog, 40); //Recebe o nome do jogador
        read(fd, &id1,sizeof(id1)); //Recebe o id do primeiro jogador
        fprintf(stdout, "Nome: %s -» %d\n", nomejog,id1);
        cont_pront++;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Nº: %d\n", cont_pront);

    //Now open in write mode and write
    fd = open(myfifo,O_WRONLY);
    if(fd == -1){
        fprintf(stdout, "Erro a abrir.\n");
    }
    if(cont_pront >= 2){
        cont_pront = -1;
    }
    write(fd, &cont_pront, sizeof(int));
    close(fd);


// optind is for the extra arguments 
// which are not parsed 
for(; optind < argc; optind++){
    if(i == 0){
        printf("Duração do campeonato: %s\n", argv[optind]);
    }else{
    if(i == 1){
        printf("Tempo de espera: %s\n", argv[optind]);
    }
    }

    i++;
}

}while(strcmp(instrucao,"exit") != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the code for cliente.c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <signal.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int fd1,cont_pront=0;
    char nomejog[40]="";
    // FIFO file path 
        char * myfifo = "myfifo";
    // Creating the named file(FIFO) 
        mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);


    // Open FIFO for write only 
        fd1 = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY); 
        //Enviar o nome do jogador ao arbitro
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){

        write(fd1, nomejog,strlen(nomejog)+1); //Envia o nome do jogador já pronto
        write(fd1,&i, sizeof(int)); //Envia o id
        strcpy(nomejog,"pedro");
    }
    close(fd1);

    //Receber quantos jogadores estão prontos
    fd1 = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);

    read(fd1, &cont_pront, sizeof(int)); //Recebe o nome do jogador

    if(cont_pront == -1){
        //Tem jogadores necessários para começar o jogo
        fprintf(stdout,"Existem jogadores suficientes, o campeonato vai ser iniciado...\n");
        execl("GAMEDIR/game01","GAMEDIR/game01", NULL);
    }else{
        //Ainda não tem jogadores suficientes para começar o jogo
        fprintf(stdout,"Nao tem jogadores suficientes para comecar o campeonato.\n");
    }
    close(fd1);
return 0; 
}
```

if everything goes well this is supposed to say that there are enough players and the executes the game, but for some reason sometimes it repeats everything sending more players in blank or the client stops midway execution or even doesn't send the correct players in the first place

Comment: The first thing to do is to check the return values of all your system calls, and `perror()` if they fail.  That will help narrow down the possible cause of the failure, and ought to be done in any case.

Comment: One bug is that the client writes a variable number of bytes for `nomejog` (1 the first time, 6 the second time) and then 4 bytes for the integer `i`.  The kernel doesn't guarantee to keep separate writes separate, so when the server attempts to read 40 bytes, it may read all 15 bytes into `nomejog` and then the remaining reads would report end of file (which you don't check for) and leave their buffers uninitialized.  You'll need to redesign your protocol so that the client and server agree as to how many bytes are expected to be sent and received for each piece of data.